# How to dockerize a nestjs app with a shared folder (between apps) and also with alias paths?

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I have a project which is written in TS on NestJs.

This is my dir structure:

```
├── README.md
├── apps
│   ├── backend
│   └── platform
├── dist
├── docker-compose.dev.yml
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
├── libs
│   └── resources
├── nest-cli.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

The libs folder is shared between the backend and the platform.
My backend Dockerfile is:

```
# Builder Stage
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json for npm install
COPY ./package*.json /usr/src/app/

# Install TypeScript globally
RUN npm install -g typescript

# Install all dependencies
RUN npm install --verbose

# Final Stage
FROM node:16-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY ./package*.json /usr/src/app/

# Copy node_modules from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules /usr/src/app/node_modules

# Copy the rest of the code
COPY . .

# Command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:backend:dev"]
```

When I build the image, it runs fine, but when I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up` , I get a LOT of errors stating my path aliases aren't recognized.
How do I make sure the aliases are recognized when I dockerize the project?

For all aliases and imports to be recognized, the same as they do when I run the project locally, not in a docker.